# HLT instruction without hlt

Tags: assembly, x86, bootloader

I'm writing bootloader for my custom kernel, it (bootloader) is based on Linux kernel v0.1 `boot.s`. Here is the code:

```
.set    BOOTSEG, 0x7c0
.set    LOADSEG, 0x9000
.set    SYSSEG, 0x1000

start:
//copy the WHOLE bootloader to new location
movw    BOOTSEG, %ax
movw    %ax, %ds
xor     %si, %si
movw    LOADSEG, %ax
movw    %ax, %es
xor     %di, %di
movw    256, %cx
rep     movsw

//jump to new location
cli
movw    LOADSEG, %ax
movw    %ax, %es
ljmp    $LOADSEG, $loaded

loaded:
// ...

movw  $0x3, %ax
int   $0x10

// ...
```

When I'm trying to jump to new location Bochs writes: `WARNING: HLT instrucion with IF=0`, but there are no `hlt` instructions at all in my code. After jump Bochs continues running, but doesn't work correctly, for example: `int $0x10` doesn't clear a screen.

May be I copied bootloader wrong, but it is similar to Linux.

So, can anybody help me with this problem?

Comment: 'cat boot.S | grep hlt' doesn't return anything?

Comment: It returns nothing for my bootloader and for Linux too.

Comment: `movw 256, %cx` - shouldn't that have a `$` on it? Possibly other places, as well?

Comment: @FrankKotler's remark also applies to `movw BOOTSEG` and `movw LOADSEG`. I believe that your goal is to get the address, not what's stored under that address in this case.

Comment: Also, real-mode BIOS service calls no longer work when protected mode is enabled.

Comment: This should case compilation error/warring, not change of opcode.

Comment: @user35443 : Quite the contrary. `movw LOADSEG, %ax` is a perfectly valid instruction, why should the assembler fail?

Comment: Sorry, in time I was writing that comment there weren't your comments, I was writing it as response on Frank Kotler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bochs says that your IF (interrupt flag, inerrupts allowed) is 0, so the problem must be in your far jump. You must make sure that

1. your code after `loaded` label doesn't contain any `hlt` instructions
2. you have correct offset for your `loaded` label (check compilator or linker settings you use)

According to your [osdev post](http://forum.osdev.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27044), you're trying to associate segment selectors of your GDT to segment registers. If you do it in real mode, values of segment registers won't be used for getting GDT entry, but they'll be shifted and added to offset as standard real-mode segments. I bet if you comment-out (or delete) the code that sets segments to GDT entries, everything will work. Try it.

The reason why it should work is simple: you change your CS segment from `LOADSEG` to `0x8`, what actually moves you somewhere to IVT space for real mode.

If you want to use GDT, you must jump to protected mode first. 
You can find more on this topic in [well written tutorials](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev8.html) on Brokenthorn.com.

Comment: Ok, I checked code one more time and I'm sure that there is no `hlt` instruction. I use `yasm` as assembler with `-f bin` flag and don't use linker, so which settings I have to change? Here is the full code (yes, it is incorrect after loaded, but error happens before it) [code, pastebin](http://pastebin.com/8dFk8MPx)

Comment: Delete lines 28-31 inclusive.

Comment: And you `jmp` to reboot, so the `loaded` label will not be reached.

Comment: Nothing changes. If I put `jmp .` before 28 line, it will go to infinite loop, but warning will alsa remain.

Comment: I know, it was just a check. In pastebin version there is no that warning.

Comment: What warrning are you speaking about? that bochs?

Comment: Yes, `WARNING: HLT with IF=0`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35608/discussion-between-user35443-and-vanzef)